# New pandas dataframe with an existing column as input to a function that maps to another value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I am creating a database of Currencies that I need to be mapped to a different code that will help me manipulate them in an easier fashion understandable by my IT system.

My database is loaded as below:

```
url = "My RawData csv"

The csv has the below format:
Underlying    Notional
AUDBRL        50,000
AUDCAD        100,000
AUDNZD        20,000 
USDJPY        15,000
AUDKRW        12,000

etc

data = pd.read_csv(url)
data = data.dropna() $
```

I am also loading a Mapping guide that I attach and I access the values there via:

```
url2 = "My Mapping csv"
Which has a format as below:
Unique CCY Pairs      CCYs
USDJPY            JPY
EURAUD            ADEU
USDRUB            RUB
AUDKRW            KWAD
EURUSD            EUR
AUDJPY            JYAD
EURJPY            JYEU

mapp = pd.read_csv(url2)
mapp = mapp.set_index('Unique CCY Pairs')
mapp.loc[CCY].values[0] $
```

where CCY is whatever currency is there at each point in time.
Now based on this I want to create a loop in my existing database that will give me the mapped value in the new CCY value column in my dataframe:

I have started with something like the below that obviously did not work and then got stuck in between lambda and map functions.

```
for CCY in data.Underlying:
 data["new"] = mapp.loc[CCY].values[0]
```

The above did not work as the data["new"] is not getting looped while the new inputs are assigned so there is only one unique value added in the new created column.
I am looking for ways to make this as effective as possible as my database will be quite big.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: IIUC, `data["new"] = mapp.loc[data.Underlying].values`

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear as to what is the expected output, but in general you can map without loop

```
data['New'] = data['Underlying'].map(mapp['CCYs'])

    Underlying  Notional    New
0   AUDBRL      50,000      NaN
1   AUDCAD      100,000     NaN
2   AUDNZD      20,000      NaN
3   USDJPY      15,000      JPY
4   AUDKRW      12,000      KWAD
```